# is it possible to get generic class by given parameter?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Assume i have "`java.util.List<java.lang.String>`" as a parameter in String. I want to get it as Class or Type, something like that:

```
ClassLoader cl=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Class clazz=cl.loadClass("java.util.List<java.lang.String>");
```

Is it possible somehow?

For instance, following code works:

```
ClassLoader cl=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Class clazz=cl.loadClass("java.util.List");
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for. You seem to **unaware** of such core things such as **raw** types and **type erasure**. You should rather turn to the books and **learn** such basics before trying to combine reflection with generics (which is kinda iffy, given the fact that generic types are well, erased at runtime).

Comment: As i updated, loading class for a just binary name works. I know types are controlled on compile type and they are erased on run time. My question does not about this, rather, how to load a class with generic type if we know its generic type before (in example, it is java.util.List<java.lang.String>)

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that you do **not** understand at all how generics work. There is no **specific** binary class for List of String versus List of Integer. There is only a List class that internally uses `Object` all over the place. One implementation to serve **all** different instantiations. Thus: turn to the books for real. You claim to know, but your comments incline ... that well, you lack knowledge.

Comment: You lack of understand what you read. Answer of @Dean Xu was exactly what i was asking for. Having some reading and understanding form what you are reading lessons might be a good choice for you. Maybe, after some generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java erasure generic in runtime. There never be a `Class` like `List<String>`.

If you want a `Type` represent `List<String>`, it should be `ParameterizedType`. You can use my utlity class [`GenericUtil`](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/297b21df13ebe25e991ec3741af21b3592e92375/src/main/java/xdean/jex/util/reflect/GenericUtil.java) to construct one

```
public static ParameterizedType createParameterizedType(Class<?> rawType, Type ownerType, Type... actualTypeArguments);

Type listString = createParameterizedType(List.class, null, String.class);
```

If you want to construct a instance of `List<String>`, you can cast the `List` to `List<String>` forcely

```
List list = ...;
List<String> listString = (List<String>)list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, I'm assuming that you want to create a class instance by his classname, so what you are looking for is the method
[Class.forName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

However as pointed out in the comment by @GhostCat you can't create a list of String, because of the TypeErasure, you can create only generic list of Object,
You should look at how generic type works: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)